# How can I import python code from the transmissionrpc addon?

Tags: xbmc, kodi

I am having trouble importing python code from a 3rd party addon.

My xml:

```
<requires>
    <import addon="xbmc.python" version="2.14.0"/>
    <import addon="script.transmission" version="0.7.6"/>
</requires>
```

When I try `import transmissionrpc` I am told that no such module exists.

Comment: Try to restart your Kodi. Might be having success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install that dependency manually for development, kodi will only resolve it when installing from zip or from the repo